# Change ISNumeric to try_convert in case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am working with old code which is performing really badly and the company is using SQL Server 2012. I read blog which states `isnumeric` performs badly so I am trying to use `try_convert` instead which is a SQL Server 2012 feature. I am seeing this statement multiple times in the code and so I want to give it shot:

```
Convert(float,Case Isnumeric(somecolumnvalue) when 1 then somecolumnvalue else 0.0 end
```

How can I convert this statement to using the `Try_convert` statement. Can any one help me please and any comments on performance issues with `isnumeric`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use:

```
coalesce(try_convert(float, somecolumn_value), 0.0)
```

I don't know if the performance will really be better, but the code is easier to read and less susceptible to unexpected problems.  Converting to `float` isn't generally troublesome, but you do have anomalies.  For instance, `'-'` "is numeric" but generates an error when converting to `float`.